# Disable keyboard events when browser is in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-fullscreen

When user clicks on a button I want to make my browser fullscreen mode and when my browser is in full screen mode, I want to disable all the keyboard events (blocking user to exit full screen). The only way to exit full screen is click event of my another button inside my page.

When I use [`Fullscreen_API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), I'm getting black color background, which looks awkward to user.

I tried with this [`package`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js), and it's working same as <kbd>F11</kbd> but my only problem with this is, disabling keyboard events.

I tried to prevent exiting with below code.

```
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Surprisingly I'm not even getting control into that when I press <kbd>esc</kbd>. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.